# : arguments must be process or job IDs624

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kill-process

I make a file in my rails app `/bin/restart_resque.sh`

```
kill  `cat tmp/pids/scheduler.pid`
```

When I execute `bin/restart_resque.sh`,I got the error

```
: arguments must be process or job IDs624
```

and the process is still working.

Then I change the file to :

```
kill  2624
```

I got the same error,but the process `2624` is do exist.why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.

when I execute `file bin/resque_restart.sh`

```
bin/resque_restart.sh: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

so the file format is the reason.but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid PID in scheduler.pid or file is not exists.

Check file and permissions:

```
namei -lm tmp/pids/scheduler.pid
```

Check PID (resque process must have PID from pid file):

```
cat tmp/pids/scheduler.pid
ps aux | grep `cat tmp/pids/scheduler.pid`
```

Comment: If I change the file to `kill  2624`,I got the same error